# Javascript: Object.Create(prototype) is not working

Tags: javascript

I am running the following in node.js:

```
function TextCell(text) {
    this.text = text.split("\n");
}

TextCell.prototype.minWidth = function() {
   return this.text.reduce(function(width, line) {
      return Math.max(width, line.length);
   }, 0);
};

TextCell.prototype.minHeight = function() {
    return this.text.length;
};

TextCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var line = this.text[i] || "";
      result.push(line + repeat(" ", width - line.length));
    }
    return result;
};

function RTextCell(text) {
    TextCell.call(this, text);
}

RTextCell.prototype = Object.create(TextCell.prototype);

RTextCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var line = this.text[i] || "";
      result.push(repeat(" ", width - line.length) + line);
    }
    return result;
};
```

When I console.log(RTextCell.prototype), I get a prototype with only the draw function. Also, when I log(Object.create(Textcell.prototype)) I just get "TextCell{}". Why does it seem like the clone of the prototype is empty?

EDIT: I noticed my mistake. I made objects of type RTextCell before defining it. That's why the prototype turned out empty. Sorry for not including that part here

Comment: [Your code seems to work fine to me.](https://jsfiddle.net/1oypy93n/) Remember that you're creating a new object whose prototype is the argument you passed it. If you're viewing it in Chrome, inspect the `__proto__` property to see the underlying prototype.

Comment: I am running it in node.js. I get errors when trying to use functions that depend on both classes having the same functions defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it seem like the clone of the prototype is empty?

Because it has no *own* properties. Inherited properties don't show up in the console directly, but when you expand the object you can follow the prototype chain.